# Chaining orX in Doctrine2 query builder

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have to dynamically add `OR` expressions to the query builder returned by `getListQueryBuilder`, right after adding a `where` clause. I can't find any suitable way of doing this, i'm just started learning Doctrine.

How can i "chain" a given number of `orX` and add them to my builder?

```
public function getListQueryBuilder($ownerId)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t');

    return $qb
        ->where($qb->expr()->eq('t.user', ':user'))
        ->setParameter('user', $ownerId);
}

$builder = getListQueryBuilder(4);

// $ORs is a dynamically builded array, here is just an example
$ORs = array();
$ORs[] = $builder->expr()->like("t.name", 'my name');
$ORs[] = $builder->expr()->like("t.description", 'desc');

// Adding ORs to the builder
$builder->andWhere($builder->expr()->orX(/* here */));
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can check [this solution](http://ominian.com/2011/06/21/doctrine2-building-where-like-expressions/):

```
$orX = $builder->expr()->orX();
foreach($ORs as $or) {
    $orX->add($or);
}
$builder->andWhere($orX);
```

Comment: If you dont want to read the full article:

    $orX = $builder->expr()->orX();
    foreach($ORs as $or)
    {
        $orX->add($or);
    }
    $builder->andWhere($orX);

Comment: @LouTerrailloune that should become part of the answer

Answer (score 10):

I stumbled on the same problem and tried :

```
$builder->andWhere($builder->expr()->orX($ORs));
```

but it does not work since orX calls "return new Expr\Orx(func_get_args());" internally and you end up with something like array(array(or1, or2))

having looked at the API however i figured you can do this:

```
$builder->andWhere($builder->expr()->orX()->addMultiple($ORs));
```

OR do use $ORs table at all but issue:

```
$orx = $builder->expr()->orX();
$orx->add($builder->expr()->like("t.name", 'my name'));
$orx->add($builder->expr()->like("t.description", 'desc'));
$builder->andWhere($orx);
```