# Doctrine ORM Criteria - dynamic orX

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine, criteria

I spent a long time on that but can't find proper solution. 
How to amend code below so I could use a variable number of dynamic contains conditions?

```
$criteria = Criteria::create();
$expr = Criteria::expr();

$criteria->where(
            $expr->orX(
                    $expr->contains('field1', $str),
                    $expr->contains('field2', $str),
                    $expr->contains('field3', $str),
                    $expr->contains('field4', $str)
            )
    );
```

Comment: I think the solution is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815047/chaining-orx-in-doctrine2-query-builder)

Answer (score 5):

You can call it dynamicly like this:

```
$criteria = new Criteria();
$expr = array();
$expr[] = $criteria->expr()->eq(/** what you want */);
$expr[] = $criteria->expr()->contains(/** what you want */);
$criteria->where(call_user_func_array(array( $criteria->expr(), 'orX' ),$expr));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this method:

```
$criteria->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('active', 'true'));
```