# Zend Db Library: How to delete multiple rows with different contraints?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

Is it possible to generate that SQL without hacking?

```
DELETE FROM product WHERE (type=1 AND deleted=1) OR (type=2 AND category=10);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this sample:

```
$db->delete(array('(type=1 AND deleted=1) OR (type=2 AND category=10)'));
```

or if  you have a model class for each table so:

```
$model = new Product();
$model->delete(array('(type=1 AND deleted=1) OR (type=2 AND category=10)'));
```

Comment: Still it seems like a hacky solution.

Comment: Exec also solves my problem. I want to find a proper way. I was trying to find a more structured way like we do in selects.

Comment: first of all if this solved your problem then you sholud accept my answer..second,this methods create a query in zend db table or zend_db_table_abstract libraries....you can take a look at them to underestand the system

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in the question i asked for a solution "without hacking". Maybe I was not clear enough. I was trying to find a solution like andX and orX of doctrine. Please check this solution for doctrine
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815047/chaining-orx-in-doctrine2-query-builder

I'll accept your solution. Thanks for your help.