# doctrine won't bind parameter to query

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Hiho,

i've got the following problem.
I want to create a query with the querybuilder with orX, andX and Like.
The query self is correctly generated but the parameters wont be bound.

The Code for create the Query:

```
 $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
 $qb->select('u')
     ->from('Application\Entity\User', 'u')
     ->andWhere(
         $qb->expr()->orx(
             $qb->expr()->andX(
                 $qb->expr()->like('u.name', ':name'),
                 $qb->expr()->like('u.lastname', ':lastname')
             ),
             $qb->expr()->like('u.email', ':email')
         )
     )
     ->setParameter('name', '%' . $findBy['name'] . '%')
     ->setParameter('lastname', '%' . $findBy['lastname'] . '%')
     ->setParameter('email', '%' . $findBy['email'] . '%');
```

A dump of getParameters() looks like the following:

```
object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)[579]
private 'elements' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parameter)[575]
          private 'name' => string 'name' (length=4)
          private 'value' => string '%Michael%' (length=9)
          private 'type' => int 2
      1 => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parameter)[576]
          private 'name' => string 'lastname' (length=8)
          private 'value' => string '%Müller%' (length=8)
          private 'type' => int 2
      2 => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parameter)[577]
          private 'name' => string 'email' (length=5)
          private 'value' => string '%mew1000@freenet.de%' (length=20)
          private 'type' => int 2`
```

Does any body has a idea why the parameter not bound into the query?

Comment: What parameter are you talking about?

Comment: The parameters set with `->setParameter('...', '...')`

Comment: What's wrong with them?

Comment: Might be that there is a problem with how you use the `orx` expression. Maybe take a look at [this answer].(http://stackoverflow.com/a/15309726/1697459). What does the SQL query look like when doctrine compiled it?

Comment: The Query looks like posted in the comment section from answer #1

Answer (score 0):

The `->expr()->like(` the second Argument to be used in LIKE() comparison. You can try something similar of:

```
$this->expr()->like('u.name', $this->expr()->literal('%'.$findBy['name'].'%'))
```

Hope this help

Comment: So the query is now correct but the result empty. If I run the query direct on the database I got a result.

Comment: Hi @MatusvonMatushausen try debugging the DQL dumping the result of `$qb->getQuery()->getSQL()` Let me know the value

Comment: the dump of getSQL: `SELECT u0_.email AS email_0, u0_.password AS password_1, u0_.lastonline AS lastonline_2, u0_.name AS name_3, u0_.lastname AS lastname_4, u0_.ip AS ip_5, u0_.token AS token_6, u0_.facebookId AS facebookId_7, u0_.userid AS userid_8, u0_.role AS role_9 FROM user u0_ WHERE (u0_.name LIKE '%User%' AND u0_.lastname LIKE '%Name%') OR u0_.email LIKE '%test@tester.de%' (length=371)`

Comment: and if you run this query in the database you find some records? What query do you mention that give you some results?

Comment: The query postet above (dump from getSQL()) works in terminal and in HeidiSQL but doctrine has no results

Comment: :) very strange, you can only check the database configuration. PS: How do you retreive the data?

Comment: The database configuration is okay. It is an existing project which is also in production. I want to add a new query and this happens now. I have a nother querybulder which generates a like statement with parameters in the same repository which works perfectly